# JBoss Drools insert facts from DRL

Tags: java, memory, rules, drools, fact

I need my WorkingMemory to be aware of facts which are created in the DRL as follows:

```
rule "Your First Rule"
when
    $testRule : TestRule(count >= 100)
then 
    System.out.println("100 PACKETS");
end
```

Is there a way of getting the WorkingMemory to become aware of the TestRule fact and then be able to be updated? My objective is to get the rule to know when 100 packets have been received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually I create something as part of a rule and use it as a flag. If you don't need to create anything, then you can create a flag, for example

```
rule "Your First Rule"
when
    $testRule : TestRule(count >= 100)
    not         Flag(id="packets")
then 
    System.out.println("100 PACKETS");
    insert( new Flag("packets") )
    update( $testRule )
end
```

I don't think this code is correct, but I think you can get the idea... And you'll need to create a class called Flag. The update is needed to tell drools that is has to update the rete tree.

Comment: This doesn't make the WorkingMemory know about any facts and I would need to insert the 'Flag' class too which still requires me to somehow make the DRL insert facts

Comment: I don't understand your point, insert() tells the WM about the fact. And you don't need to insert the Flag class into the working memory from java, you just need to import it in the DRL, and the rule will insert the fact.

Comment: Then perhaps I have some bad code somewhere. At the moment my WorkingMemory isn't picking up any facts from the DRL...

Comment: I added an extra bit (the `update( $testrule)`) that might help. It's very odd that you can insert a fact from the rules. In the app I'm working we insert only one object from java, and then we have about 60 rules that explode that object into lots of facts.

Comment: I believe it is something to do with where I create the Packages, RuleBase and WorkingMemory